# List FactoryBot created records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, factory-bot

I'm trying to use FactoryBot to create new records programmatically `FactoryBot.create(factory_name, parsed_traits, record_fields)`
Is it possible to list all records created when `FactoryBot.create` is invoked?
For example a factory :user has two traits :supplier and :buyer this traits have before and after blocks that will create other records.
I'm able to list all the record types created by subscribing to `ActiveSupport::Notifications.subscribe("sql.active_record", insert_subscriber)` but since it's not guaranteed that the records created have a direct association this doesn't give me enough information.

Comment: What do you want to achieve by that? Could you provide more examples?

Comment: I wan't to be able to map the created associations to the main record.
For example a when a user of type supplier is created we create a supplier group and a brand, I would like to be able to return a result tree with the created records like
`Supplier { Supplier Group { Brand } }`

Comment: Could you show the schema of data and your current factories?

Comment: The solution I'm looking for would have to have some level of abstraction from any particular schema so it would work with all models/factories
But for example 
Schema => User(role: supplier), SupplierGroupAccess belongs_to supplier_group and user, SupplierGroup has_many brands
Factory => User trait :supplier { after(:create) create :supplier_group_access, user: user }
Factory => SupplierGroupAccess association {:user, :supplier} association {:supplier_group}
`create :user, :supplier`
So in this case FactoryBot will return the user and I would like to also return the associated records

Comment: I believe you can call associated records on a created user if you set up relations properly `user = create(:user, :supplier)`, `user.supplier_group.brands` it is not about `FactoryBot` it is about models relations.